# Выборка нескольких полей с использованием DISTINCT

Tags: select, sql

Помогите сформировать sql запрос

```
SELECT DISTINCT news FROM `comments` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

- это работает, но выбирается только поле news, а мне надо id, news, reg, name, comment,date_add

```
SELECT DISTINCT news,id,news,reg,name,comment,date_add FROM `comments` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

- этот не работает

Answer (score 2):

`DISTINCT` - это уникальность по всем полям ( практически тоже самое что `GROUP BY` по всем полям )

То что хотите, можно как-то так:

```
select `c`.*
from
  (
    select
      `news`,
      `last`
    from
      (
        select
          max( `id` ) `last`,
          `news`
        from
          `comments`
        group by
          `news`
      ) `l`
    order by
      `last` desc
    limit 10
  ) `l`,
  `comments` `c`
where
  `c`.`news` = `l`.`news` and
  `c`.`id` = `l`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
SELECT * FROM comments GROUP BY news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```